# Initializing a 2d array then transposing it

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, 2d

Beginner here, I'm looking to write a program in C that initializes each row of a 8 x 10 matrix, A[8][10], with the value of the row (the first row contains all 0's, the second row contains all 1's etc.)

after printing this matrix I want to transpose it, making a second matrix B[10][8]

I'm trying to use nested for loops but I can't seem to get even close to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in your own code, here's an sample for you:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define ROWS 8
#define COLS 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int A[ROWS][COLS];
    int B[COLS][ROWS];
    int i,j;

    /*populate*/
    for (i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<COLS; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = 2*i + j;
        }
    }

    /*display*/
    printf("=== Original matrix === \n");

    for (i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<COLS; j++)
        {
            printf("%3d  ", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    /*transpose*/
    for (i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<COLS; j++)
        {
            B[j][i] = A[i][j];
        }
    }


    /*display*/
    printf("\n\n=== Transposed matrix === \n");

    for (i=0; i<COLS; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<ROWS; j++)
        {
            printf("%3d  ", B[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> === Original matrix ===
>
> 0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
>
> 2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
>
> 4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
>
> 6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15
>
> 8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17
>
> 10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
>
> 12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21
>
> 14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23
>
> === Transposed matrix ===
>
> 0    2    4    6    8   10   12   14
>
> 1    3    5    7    9   11   13   15
>
> 2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16
>
> 3    5    7    9   11   13   15   17
>
> 4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18
>
> 5    7    9   11   13   15   17   19
>
> 6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20
>
> 7    9   11   13   15   17   19   21
>
> 8   10   12   14   16   18   20   22
>
> 9   11   13   15   17   19   21   23

Comment: This is a great help thank you. I'm trying to alter the for loops so I get the first row to be all 0's, then the next row to be all 1's etc. Inside the for loop is where I can accomplish this right? thanks again

Comment: To do this, in the populate loop, you need A[i][j] = i;

Comment: Just tried that as you commented. This is great thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The GSL - GNU Scientific Library may help.

http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

They have a similar example here http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Example-programs-for-matrices.html#Example-programs-for-matrices